# How to get a standard object by standard field with rest api?

Tags: rest-api

I am new to salesforce development.
I wonder what is the correct rest api if I want to get a standard object by using a field instead of id?
For example, if I want to get a contact record by id, I try below command:

> curl
>   https://cs10.salesforce.com/services/data/v33.0/sobjects/Contact/Id/003J000001CxKKsIAN
>   -H "Authorization: Bearer myAccessToken" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET

(I know Node "Id" could be omitted) it returns as expected:

```
{"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v33.0/sobjects/Contact/003J000001CxKKsIAN"},"Id":"003J000001CxKKsIAN","IsDeleted":false,"MasterRecordId":null,"AccountId":"001J000001bXQZHIA4",...}
```

However, if I want to retrieve this record by *account id*:

> curl
>   https://cs10.salesforce.com/services/data/v33.0/sobjects/Contact/AccountId/001J000001bXQZHIA4
>   -H "Authorization: Bearer myAccessToken" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET

it returns error:

```
[{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"Provided external ID field does not exist or is not accessible: AccountId"}]
```

What is the correct example for my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that only if you are using a External Id, AccountId is not. 
What you can do it to make a simple query ([doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm)):

**Endpoint**

```
/services/data/v32.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id%2C+FirstName%2C+LastName+FROM+Contact+WHERE+AccountId+%3D+%2700128000002lyIm%27
```

Comment: so, you mean, if the query element is not the primary key or external id, I should use query instead of a rest call like mine, right?

Comment: That's right, otherwise you can create your own apex rest api, but then it will requires more development on salesforce side.

Comment: Same to do update action, right? I mean, I also need write my own sql to execute an update if I want to update the record by one of its field (instead of external id), right?

Comment: If external Id, you could update straight away your contact without its id. If you are using another field than an external id, you will need to make 2 calls, the first one to GET the record contact and its id, then another one to update(POST) the contact using the id.